# htaccess rwrite images folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

My web site opens normally, but does not load the folder of images, css, js, etcs

The path to the correct folder is: http://www.example.com/themes/leotrav/css/bootstrap.css"

but the folder that is being loaded is: http://www.example.com/tours/themes/leotrav/css/bootstrap.css"

I want to remove /tours/ for loading images

How can I change this?

Comment: What's the content of your .htaccess file? There's a rewrite already in place, it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule as very first rule `DocumentRoot/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^tours/(.+?\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js))$ /$1 [L,NC,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: worked perfect! ty :) can you explain me what does the "[L, NC, NE, R = 301]"?

Comment: L - Last Rule, NC - ignore case, NE - No encode, R=301 is for redirect with 301 status. See this also: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html